# Symfony 3.4 : FOS User Bundle sending mail with gmail not working

Tags: symfony, email, gmail, symfony-3.4

I'm working with ***Symfony 3.4 lts*** and I installed the ***FOS User Bundle*** ***2.0*** and I'm testing different actions:

Register: OK (User created but not receiving the mail)

Login: OK

forgot password : NOK  (I'm not receiving the mail)

So I think that the problem is in the mail configuration:

```
#parameters.yml:

parameters:

    database_host: XXXXXX        
    database_port: XXXXXX
    database_name: XXXXXX
    database_user: XXXXXX
    database_password: XXXXXX
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: XXXXXX@gmail.com
    mailer_password: XXXXXX
    secret: XXXXXX

#config.yml

swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
    service:                               
    mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
    resetting:
        email:
            from_email:
                address:        %mailer_user%
                sender_name:    Demo Resetting
```

Can someone can help me ?

Comment: Checkout: [How to Work with Emails during Development](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/dev_environment.html#disabling-sending)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: mail_acount@gmail.com
mailer_password: your_pwd
```

You need to set a real mailer_host or define a configuration that specify your are in a dev environment.

Comment: I have putten what you have mentioned in mailer_transport & mailer_host but it still not working, I try to send mail via command line :
 Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "myMail@gmail.com" using 1 possible authenticators

Comment: You need to use real credentials (user and password) because you are actually connecting to gmail mail server. You need to confirm access from your pc to gmail mail servers.

Comment: it works for me as you write but without specifying the mailer_host.